# Copy a formula with cell reference

Tags: excel

I have a pretty long formula that I want to exact copy to another sheet, but I want to set the cell references to the original sheet.

For example:

`=$A1+B$2`

If I copy it to another sheet it needs to be:

`='original_sheet'!$A1+'original_sheet'!B$2`

I have a very long formula and I want to copy a few formulas like this so adding a 'original_sheet'! before each cell reference is pretty painful.

Is there any built-in way to do this in excel?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the cell where the formula is in the original, and copy it from the formula bar to the clipboard, then paste it in the copy in the same cell address. Providing layout is identical this should be no issue...